# XNA - How Can I Edit A Rectangles Bounds From Another Class

Tags: c#, windows, xna

So I have this problem where I have a variable called StarBounds in my main game class file. The file is now called MainGameClass.cs with namespace StarCatcher.

I have made a class to detect if the mouse is hovered over the StarBounds variable and then clicks. On click I would like to edit the StarBounds variable from this other class called GameFunctions.cs.

I am able to do something like...
MainGameClass mgc = new MainGameClass();

The when the hover and click event is triggered I can type in without errors:
mgc.StarBounds = new rectangle(0,0,0,0);

But in the actual game it does not change. And also I sometimes get errors when doing the "mgc.StarBounds = new rectangle(0,0,0,0);" saying it doesn't have an object reference.

Comment: you should pass a reference to this variable to the code that is supposed to modify its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most likely just a **scope issue**. The exception is caused because mgc is null. Make sure that GameFunctions has not declared a local copy of MainGameClass and is referencing a pre-existing instance. Otherwise, use a static variable for StarBounds as shown in the example. Example,

```
public class MainGameClass {
    public static Rectangle StarBounds;

    public void HandleInput () {
        // if GameFunctions.ClickedWithinStarBounds(mouse)
        // GameFunctions.OnClickStarBounds()
    }
}

public class GameFunctions {
    public static void ClickedWithinStarBounds(MouseState mouse) {
        // create a rectangle around the mouse (ie. cursor) for the detection area
        // return left mouse button is down or pressed && IsWithinStarBounds
    }

    public static bool IsWithingStarBounds(Rectangle area) {
        return (MainGameClass.StarBounds.Intersects(area);
    }

    public static void OnClickStarBounds() {
        MainGameClass.StarBounds = Rectangle.Empty;
    }
}
```